# Creating a new Freebsd port

Tags: python, package, freebsd, ports

I am trying to create a new freeBsd port for [cogapp 2.2](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cogapp/) . I use the following makefile which actually fetches the tar.gz as expected but does not use easy install to install the package.

```
# New ports collection makefile for:    cogapp
# Whom:                 Karthick   
#
# $FreeBSD: ports/devel/py-virtualenv/Makefile,v 1.21 2011/03/12 23:53:13 nivit Exp $
#

PORTNAME=       cogapp
PORTVERSION=    2.2
CATEGORIES=     devel python
MASTER_SITES=   http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cogapp/

MAINTAINER=     xyz@FreeBSD.org
COMMENT=        cog port

USE_PYDISTUTILS=        easy_install

.include <bsd.port.mk>
```

It rather throws the following error

```
 ===>  Vulnerability check disabled, database not found
===>  License check disabled, port has not defined LICENSE
===>  Extracting for cogapp-2.2
=> No checksum file (/tmp/cogapp-2.2/distinfo).
===>  Patching for cogapp-2.2
===>  Configuring for cogapp-2.2
===>  Building for cogapp-2.2
make: cannot open Makefile.
*** Error code 1
```

Stop in /tmp/cogapp-2.2.

Can anyone suggest me a solution for  this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worked for me with these changes:

```
USE_PYTHON=yes
USE_PYDISTUTILS=yes
```

And while i'm there:

- USE_PYTHON defines which python versions are working with this port.
  If it's "yes", then all python version are supported.
- Run 'make makesum' to create distinfo file for your port.
- You also would need to create packing list (a list of files, that are
  installed by port). For this i'm using helper script written by
  FreeBSD developer amdmi3: [link](http://amdmi3.ru/files/pt)
  For this, run 'pt i && pt plist' inside your port dir.

Comment: Excellent! I had figured the main problem out. But I was wondering how to create package and your answer explains it really well! Thanks a ton!